# Inequality involving resultant of two polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Suppose $w$ is a complex number, and set $c=\max(1,|w|)$. If $F$ and $G$ are non-zero polynomials in one indeterminate with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$, and $\deg(F)=d$ and $\deg(G)=d'$, with $|F|,|G|\geq 1$. If $R$ is their [resultant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant), then why is
$$
|R|\leq c^{d+d'}[|F(w)|+|G(w)|]|F|^{d'}|G|^d(d+d')^{d+d'}?
$$

Here, I'm using $|F|$ to be the maximum of the absolute values of the coefficients of $F$. Thanks for any suggestions on approaching this.

The Source of this problem is Serge Lang's Algebra, exercise 16 of Chapter IV.

Comment: Could you indicate why you believe this is true ? Or, maybe, give a reference where such an inequality is stated.

Comment: In your inequality, should $|R|$ be $|R(w)|$? Otherwise, why is the right hand side related to #\$w$?

Comment: @Sasha Sure, I will do that.

Comment: Must be a different edition. Chapter IV of my copy of Lang's Algebra is Homology, and the only exercise in it is the notorious one, "Take any book on homological algebra, and prove all the theorems without looking at the proofs given in that book." Found it! In my edition, it's Chapter V, exercise 13.